# Symfony repository case sensitivity Issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to search for the name, surname and company name of the customers in the database, but there is no result. What could be the reason for this? I did `'%'.$search.'%'` but the result is blank. I think it is case sensitive. How can I solve this?

Repository:

```php
public function search(string $search)
    {
        $search = trim($search);
        if (!$search) {
            return null;
        }

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('customers');

        return $query->where('customers.name LIKE :search OR customers.lastname LIKE :search OR customers.company_name LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter('search', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

    }
```

```
Name : Berkay
Lastname : Cooke

Working Get : /customerSearch?q=Berkay - erkay - erk
Not Working Get : /customerSearch?q=berkay
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  Mysql is case insensitive but PostgreSQL is sensitive.  I'd also suggest running the query from a database console window until you get the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony Doctrine does not have a keyword to match case-insensitive patterns. As a workaround, you can try this (not tested):

```
public function search(string $search)
{
    $search = strtolower(trim($search));
    if (!$search) {
        return null;
    }

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('customers');

    return $query
        ->where('
            LOWER(customers.name) LIKE :search OR
            LOWER(customers.lastname) LIKE :search OR
            LOWER(customers.company_name) LIKE :search
        ')
         ->setParameter('search', '%'.$search.'%')
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult();
}
```

Please note the two important changes:

- Use the function `strtolower()` at the beginning of the function;
- Use the DQL keyword `LOWER` in the query.

Comment: likewise I am having a special character problem. For example : `Özel - özel` How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can try to replace `strtolower()` by `mb_strtolower()`